# Übersetzung von „unmöglich am Ziel angekommen sein können“

Tags: translation, german-to-english, standard-german

Neulich habe ich einen Artikel über die Geschichte des Fortschritts in einem Buch gelesen. In diesem Artikel gibt es eine Aussage, die ich nicht komplett verstehen kann, oder nicht korrekt ins Englische übersetzen kann.

Die Aussage ist :

> Die Geschichte zeigt, dass wir unmöglich am Ziel angekommen sein können.

Mein erster Gedanke der Übersetzung war :

> History shows us that we can achieve/arrive at the impossible Goal.

Und um dann meine Übersetzung zu überprüfen, überprüfte ich dieselbe auf Google Translate und Bing. Und jedes mal bekam ich die gleiche Antwort :

> > History shows that it is impossible for us to reach our goal

Aber ich kann diese Übersetzung nicht komplett nachvollziehen.
Warum sollte der Autor in einem Artikel über Fortschritt in diesem negativen Tonfall sprechen.

Ich verstehe, Google Translate/Bing  sind nicht immer richtig bei Übersetzung.   Deswegen stelle ich diese Frage hier.

Könnte jemand die richtige Übersetzung hier als Antwort schreiben bitte?

Comment: Mein Vorschlag: The story shows that it can't be that we have reached the goal.

Comment: @Harald Better _"History shows ..."_

Comment: @Harald I'm not sure, because the author started from stone age and then goes onto Intergalactic travel and and so on. Then talks about what may come further for future generations. So going by that logic, there cannot be a single goal, because the progress in this case is eternal... But this particular statement I just cannot make a sense of...

Comment: Ich denke, um diesen Satz zu verstehen, braucht man erst mal den weiteren Kontext. Um was geht es?

Comment: Während Googles und Bings Übersetzungen oft zu wünschen übrig lassen, ist deepL da schon im eines weiter.

Comment: @infinitezero Ich stimme zu. Aber ich vermute, sie verwenden es bereits in einigen Form. Vielleicht mit besserer Entwicklung von RNN/Feedback Networks wird die Ergebnisse im Laufe der Zeit verbessern.

Comment: Das mag sein. Dennoch empfehle ich bei Unklarheiten und besonders dann, wenn Google nicht weiterhilft deepL.com

Comment: Ah ok... Ich dachte, bei deepL meintest du „Deep Learning“. Was ich dachte und was du meintest waren nicht ausgerichtet. Dennoch, Danke für die Auskunft über deepL.com :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A precise translation is:

> History shows that we can't possibly have reached the goal.

It implies that we will still progress further from hereon. Maybe we'll never reach our goal.

*Die Geschichte* could also mean *the story*, depending on context. gnasher729 pointed this out in the comments.

Comment: “Geschichte” could be “history” or “the story” depending on context.

Answer (score 3):

> Die Geschichte zeigt, dass wir unmöglich am Ziel angekommen sein können.

*Unmöglich* ist eine Verneinung; obwohl es den Sinn leicht verändert, können wir es bis auf weiteres durch *nicht* ersetzen. Das gibt uns:

> Die Geschichte zeigt, dass wir nicht am Ziel angekommen sein können.

Jetzt müssen wir die Verben aufschlüsseln. *Können* ist ein reines Hilfsverb, lassen wir es erst einmal weg:

> Die Geschichte zeigt, dass wir nicht am Ziel angekommen sind.

So weit vereinfacht sollte hoffentlich der Sinn des Satzes klar geworden sein. Und er lässt sich recht einfach übersetzen:

> History shows that we have not reached the goal.

(Im Englischen sollte hier das Perfekt stehen, weil es um den Gegenwartszustand geht, der von der Vergangenheit geschaffen wurde.)

Das Hilfsverb dazu:

> History shows that we cannot have reached the goal.

Und das *unmöglich*? Von der Wörter her ist es ein Adverb. Im Englischen kommt es eher selten vor, dass ein verneintes Adverb verwendet wird; häufiger wird ein positives Adverb in Verbindung mit *not* benutzt. Daher:

> History shows that we cannot possibly have reached the goal.

Comment: Gute Erklärung Jan. Danke :)

Comment: Sehr hilfreiche Analyse. Meine frühere Antwort war eher intuitiv.

Answer (score 2):

The key to successfully translating the sentence in question lies in recognising the fact that *unmöglich* can be used to negate the verb, just like *nicht*.

> Die Geschichte zeigt, dass wir **unmöglich** am Ziel angekommen sein **können**.
>
> History shows that we **cannot** possibly have reached the end.

This leads to ambiguities that English doesn't have.

> Das kann unmöglich sein.
>   1) This can be impossible.
>   2) This cannot possibly be (the case).

In the first case, *unmöglich* is a [predicative complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement) of *sein* and translated as *impossible*. In the second, the predicative complement is elided (cf. the optional *the case* in the translation); *unmöglich* negates the verb and is rendered in English as *not possibly*.

Comment: Thanks David, I agree. If not for unmöglich, this translation would have been pretty much straightforward, but that slightly complicated things, which is where the ambiguity arrived.